# How to replace value in array of dictionary in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have array of dictionary, I am trying to store it in NSuserdefault  but as it contain `<null>` app get crash, can we replace `<null>` with ""?
Is there any way to resolve this issue?

This is my array of dictionaries:

```
var array = (
                            {
                    ClinicID = "<null>";
                    "Patient_SurveyID" = 1956;
                    "Patient_Treatment_PlanID" = "<null>";
                    PhysicianID = "<null>";
                },
                            {
                    ClinicID = "<null>";
                    "Patient_SurveyID" = 1956;
                    "Patient_Treatment_PlanID" = "<null>";
                    PhysicianID = "<null>";
                },
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have an array of dictionaries

```
let list: [[String:Any]] = []
```

and each dictionary is of type `[String:Any]`.

This is the code to replace the NSNull values into your dictionaries with 
`""`

```
let list: [[String:Any] = []

let updatedDict = list.map { (dict) -> [String:Any] in
    let keysWithEmptStringValue = dict.filter { $0.1 is NSNull }.map { $0.0 }
    var dict = dict
    for key in keysWithEmptStringValue {
        dict[key] = ""
    }
    return dict
}
```

### From NSMutableArray to [[String:Any]]

To convert your NSMutableArray to a Swift generic array please try this code

```
let array = NSMutableArray()
let list: [[String:Any]] = array.flatMap { $0 as? [String:Any] }
```

Comment: Perfect answer! But my array is NSMutableArray, this is not working for that

Comment: @sss: I added some code to perform the conversion, please check it out

Comment: @appzYourLife I suppose the OP wants to replace the `NSNull` instances in the dictionary string representation with empty strings.

Comment: @vadian: You are right, I totally misunderstood the question!

Comment: Working! Thank You for help :)